# Limit the vector position to be passed in a function as parameter

Tags: c++, vector

I am think of limiting the index to be passed on a function.

main.cpp:

```
typedef vector<int *> my_int;
my_int a;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    a.push_back(i);  

calc1(a); //(Note:This is wrong) start the data from 0 until 3 only
calc2(a.begin() + 5); //(Note:This is wrong) start data from 4 to 7 only
```

I would like to pass it to my functions calc1() and calc2().

```
int calc1(my_int *d)
{
    for (my_int::iterator it = d.begin(); i != d.end(); ++i)
        printf("%d ", *it);
}
```

The output should be:

```
0 1 2 3
```

While on

```
int calc2(my_int *d)
{
    for (my_int::iterator it = d.begin(); i != d.end(); ++i)
        printf("%d ", *it);
}
```

The output should be:

```
4 5 6 7
```

My syntax is not particularly accurate as I haven't tested it yet. But I just wanna know first how to implement this kind of situation.

Comment: _`calc1(&a); calc2(&a.begin() + 5);`_ is syntactically wrong, no matter if an iterator or pointer is used. Rather use something like `int calc2(const std::vector<double>& start, const std::vector<double>& end)`.

Comment: @Gibs yelling at people doesn't alter the fact that a question without gratuitous syntax errors is a clearer question.

Comment: @Gibs STOP SHOUTING AT ME, OK! I've been well reading this, but that doesn't make the question better.

Comment: Okay sorry, I just don't know how to construct the question right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough to write only one function like this

```
int calc( std::vector<int>::iterator first, std::vector<int>::iterator last );
```

And call it like

```
calc( my_int.begin(), std::next( my_int.begin(), 4 ) );
calc( std::next( my_int.begin(), 4 ), my_int.end() );
```

Or you can declare the function the following way

```
int calc_n( std::vector<int>::iterator first, size_t n );
```

and call it like

```
calc_n( my_int.begin(), 4 );
calc_n( std::next( my_int.begin(), 4 ), 4 );
```